# The '==' operator is not working correctly in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following piece of code is behaving incorrectly in my script:

```
from ctypes import *

base_addr = c_uint64(0)
base_addr_temp = c_uint64(0)
print base_addr
print base_addr_temp
if(base_addr == base_addr_temp):
    print "val"
```

The output that I get:

> c_ulong(0L)
>
> c_ulong(0L)

I am using Python version 2.7.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that because these are objects, you'd have to compare them by value:

```
base_addr.value == base_addr_temp.value
```

It's been a while since I've done any Python, but in many languages, two objects are only considered "equal" if they actually refer to the same object (i.e. reference the same location in memory).

Comment: The same code works if the data type is int(0). I was under the impression that '!=' operator will handle the scenario as the same way it does for int. Isn't int also implemented as a class in python ?

Comment: `!=` uses the logic that the class defines for it. If the class itself has none, then as usual the superclass etc. are checked, all the way up to `object` - which does an identity comparison. `int` happens to have value-comparison logic built in, because the language would be unusable for mathematics otherwise :)

Comment: -1. '==' operator doesn't compare by references, ie. if a and b are different objects with same values, a == b is True. 'is' is the operator which checks whether the 2 variables actually are same object. I feel sorry for -1 as I don't know the correct answer myself but this is incorrect AFAIK :).

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison is between the addresses of two objects ("base_addr" and "base_addr_temp"), not between the values of your two objects (which are both 0L).

Weirdly, on Windows and using Python 2.7.3, base_addr.**str**() returns 'c_ulonglong(0L)' which is different from what you saw, but that doesn't change the fact that you were comparing data locations rather than values.

Comment: It's more complex than that (and I do not have an answer). If you do: a=[0,];b=[0,];a==b it will return True. Both a and b are lists (thus objects) but == compare values. Same result if I do a=[0,]; b=a.copy(); a==b. Can the answer to the question be related to ctypes peculiarities?